# При запуске парсера ничего не выводится

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

При запуске парсера ничего не выводится

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parce():
    URL = 'https://www.olx.kz/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/q-Компьютеры/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 YaBrowser/21.9.0.1044 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }

    respons = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respons.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'offer promoted')
    comps = [] 

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            "title": item.find('a', class_ = 'marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink linkWithHashPromoted').get_text(strip = True)
        })        

        for comp in comps:
            print(f'{comp["title"]}')

parce()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parce():
    URL = 'https://www.olx.kz/elektronika/kompyutery-i-komplektuyuschie/q-Компьютеры/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 YaBrowser/21.9.0.1044 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
    }
    respons = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respons.content, 'html.parser')


    items = soup.find_all('td', {"class": "offer promoted"})
    comps = [] 

    for item in items:
        title = item.find('h3', {"class":"lheight22 margintop5"}).text.replace('\n', '')
        comps.append(title)     

    for i in comps:
        print(i)

parce()
```

Все потому, что это не работает `items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'offer promoted')` и ваш список items пустой